# List<Object> as dependecy property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a dependency property to pass a `List<Object>` to my custom validation class but I get the following error:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'TimeSheetRowList' property of type 'WpfApp1_Services_Wrapper_2_252121760'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Views.Installer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Views"
         xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Services"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
      >
<Grid>
        <DataGrid >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time from" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <Binding Path="TimeFrom" StringFormat="HH:mm" ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <validation:TimeIntervalValidation>
                                    <validation:TimeIntervalValidation.Wrapper >
                                        <validation:Wrapper TimeSheetRowList="{Binding DataList}"/>
                                    </validation:TimeIntervalValidation.Wrapper>
                                </validation:TimeIntervalValidation>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public class TimeIntervalValidation:ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
       // method implementation           
    }

    public  Wrapper Wrapper { get; set; }

}

public class Wrapper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeSheetRowCollectionProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("TimeSheetRowList", typeof(IList<TimeSheetRow>),
         typeof(Wrapper),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             new ObservableCollection<TimeSheetRow>()
         ));

    public ObservableCollection<TimeSheetRow> TimeSheetRowList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<TimeSheetRow>)GetValue(TimeSheetRowCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TimeSheetRowCollectionProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Tried to close project then clean and rebuild solution but doesn't work. To mention I am only getting the error mentioned above only when entering in XAML, otherwise if I just build solution I do not get any errors before going to XAML.

Comment: The DataList property that the View is binding to, is not in the Wrapper class. Please update the code.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Yes it is not in the Wrapper class, it is in the ViewModel

Comment: **Warning**: using `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<TimeSheetRow>())` means that every 'instance' has the **SAME default value**, so uses the same instance. Mutating one list, affects all other instances. There is only one instance. You should set the value of the `TimeSheetRowList` in the constructor.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I changed to `null` as it says in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

When you use `typeof(IList<TimeSheetRow>)` as property type argument of the `Register` method, you must also use that type for the property wrapper.

Besides that, you must not set any other value than `null` for the default value of collection-type properties. Otherwise all instances of the `Wrapper` class would use the same single default collection object.

Also adhere to naming conventions for the depenency property identifier field.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeSheetRowListProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         nameof(TimeSheetRowList),
         typeof(IList<TimeSheetRow>),
         typeof(Wrapper),
         new PropertyMetadata(null));

public IList<TimeSheetRow> TimeSheetRowList
{
    get { return (IList<TimeSheetRow>)GetValue(TimeSheetRowListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TimeSheetRowListProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: They were also same name  and the same result

Comment: Ok I cannot do that cause I need setter too but I did the following and the error still shows : I added this line `Wrapper = new Wrapper();` in constructor

Comment: @GabrielCostin Sorry, that was nonsense. You are already assigning a value to the Wrapper property in XAML.

Comment: The property I am binding to must be in the Wrapper class too?  I am talking about this line of code :   <validation:Wrapper TimeSheetRowList="{Binding DataList}"/>  , `DataList` is a property of the ViewModel

Comment: No, but the Binding will probably not work because the DataContext is not inherited. You may have to explicitly set the Binding's Source or RelativeSource.

Comment: Ok I will figure out after , first I want to get rid of this error

Comment: What if you create the Wrapper as a resource in Window.Resources. like `<validation:Wrapper TimeSheetRowList="{Binding DataList}" x:Key="Wrapper"/>` and use it by `<validation:TimeIntervalValidation 
Wrapper="{StaticResource Wrapper}"/>`?

Comment: I did and I get the same error , and btw it is not window it is usercontrol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198993/discussion-between-gabriel-costin-and-clemens).

Comment: you know what else would be the problem?